# Select group that have certain distinct value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

WIth the below table, i want to select the `IDNO` that has only one type `4001` which is `IDNO 2001` so that I can determine and update the total_owe to '0.00'.

```
IDNO    Type    Money       Total_owe
----    -----   --------    ---------
1001    300     900.00      1900.00
1001    300     200.00      1900.00
1001    300     800.00      1900.00
1001    4001    200.00      1900.00

2001    4001    100.00      0.00
2001    4001    100.00      0.00

3001    300     100.00      200.00
3001    300     100.00      200.00
```

How do I modify the below query so that it only select `IDNO` that have only one type '4001' ?

```
select * from table group by IDNO having count(distinct type) = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything for *color type* or the value *green* but the below query should return what you want

```
select *
from YourTable
where IDNO in (select IDNO from YourTable group by IDNO having count(distinct Type) = 1)
and Type = 4001
```

Comment: edited the question. haha. is there anyway to select it without a nested query?

Comment: You could use a CTE, but what's wrong with the IN clause? If you **only** want the `INDO` and not the entire row, then that is possible, just specify...